# Member function pointers in a hierarchy

Tags: c++, casting, pointer-to-member

I'm using a library that defines an interface:

```
template<class desttype>
void connect(desttype* pclass, void (desttype::*pmemfun)());
```

and I have a small hierarchy

```
class base {
   void foo();
};

class derived: public base { ... };
```

In a member function of `derived`, I want to call

```
connect(this, &derived::foo);
```

but it seems that `&derived::foo` is actually a member function pointer of `base`; gcc spits out

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘connect(derived* const&, void (base::* const&)())’
```

I can get around this by explicitly casting `this` to `base *`; but why can't the compiler match the call with `desttype = base` (since `derived *` can be implicitly cast to `base *`)?

Also, why *is* `&derived::foo` not a member function pointer of `derived`?

Comment: Is there a really good reason to use a pointer to a member function instead of just declaring a (pure?) virtual function in the base, and calling it when needed?

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: When there is - there is. The only way to call a pure virtual function is through a hardcoded name of that function. When hardcoding a specific function is not acceptable, pointers-to-members are used. This must be one of those cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firstly, when you do `&class::member` the type of the result is always based on the class that member actually declared in. That's just how unary `&` works in C++.

Secondly, the code does not compile because the template argument deduction fails. From the first argument it derives that `desttype = derived`, while from the second one it derives that `desttype = base`. This is what makes the compilation to fail. The template argument deduction rules in C++ don't consider the fact that `this` can be converted to `base *` type. Moreover, one can argue that instead of converting `this` to `base *` type, the proper way would be to convert `&derived::foo` from pointer-to-base-member to pointer-to-derived-member type. Both approaches are equally viable (see below).

Thirdly, member pointers in C++ obey the rules of *contra-variance*, which means that a pointer to a base class member can be implicitly converted to a pointer to a derived class member. In your case, all you need to do is to help the compiler get through template argument deduction by specifying the argument explicitly, and the code should compile

```
 connect<derived>(this, &derived::foo);
```

The above should compile because of *contra-variance* of `&derived::foo` pointer, even though it is a pointer to `base` member. Alternatively you can do

```
 connect<base>(this, &derived::foo);
```

This should also compile because of *covariance* of `this` pointer.

You can also use explicit casts on the actual arguments (as you mention in the question) to get through the deduction ambiguity, but in my opinion in this case the explicitly specified template argument looks better.

Comment: @AndreyT, thanks, I didn't think of explicitly specifying the template argument. As for my second question, I think I've pieced it together based on your explanation, but I'd suggest combining your "firstly" and "thirdly" - my guess (though I could be wrong) is that the *reason* the type of a member function pointer is based in the class it's declared in is that member function pointers are contravariant, not covariant. If `&derived::foo` returned a member function in `derived`, it wouldn't be able to be called on a `base *`.

Comment: Sometimes you just need someone to put words on concepts and explain what they represent... man do I love SO for this! Very nice explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Member function pointers have a lot of idiosyncrasies in C++, and various compilers have inconsistencies in how they work.  Doug Clugston's article, ["Member Function Pointers and the Fastest Possible C++ Delegates"](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx), is a very nice overview of how they work (and don't work):

> when dealing with derived classes,
>   there are some surprises. For example,
>   the code below will compile on MSVC if
>   you leave the comments intact:
>
> ```
> class SomeClass {
>  public: 
>     virtual void some_member_func(int x, char *p) {
>        printf("In SomeClass"); };
> };
>
> class DerivedClass : public SomeClass {
>  public:
>  // If you uncomment the next line, the code at line (*) will fail!
>
> //    virtual void some_member_func(int x, char *p) { printf("In DerivedClass"); };
>
> };
>
> int main() {
>     // Declare a member function pointer for SomeClass
>
>     typedef void (SomeClass::*SomeClassMFP)(int, char*);
>     SomeClassMFP my_memfunc_ptr;
>     my_memfunc_ptr = &DerivedClass::some_member_func; // ---- line (*)
> }
> ```
>
> Curiously enough,
>   `&DerivedClass::some_member_func` is a
>   member function pointer of class
>   `SomeClass`. It is not a member of
>   `DerivedClass`! (Some compilers behave
>   slightly differently: e.g., for
>   Digital Mars C++,
>   `&DerivedClass::some_member_func` is
>   undefined in this case.) But, if
>   `DerivedClass` overrides
>   `some_member_func`, the code won't
>   compile, because
>   `&DerivedClass::some_member_func` has
>   now become a member function pointer
>   of class `DerivedClass`!

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem of template argument deduction, if the template arguments are not explicitly stated on the invocation site, then the compiler will not try to do automatic conversion.

The best way to get around this, in my experience, is to declare two template arguments for the function:

```
template<typename Y, typename T>
void connect(Y * pclass, void (T::*pmemfun)());
```

In this case, the compiler can happily automatically instantiate for you

```
void connect<derived, base>(derived * pclass, void (base::*pmemfun)());
```

This solution is also perfectly safe, since the conversion from derived * to base * will be done inside connect (where I assume you are calling pclass->*pmemfun() )

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't (without undue effort, at least) change the signature of the method.

Comment: In that case, the only solution left is to explicitly specify the template argument, as AndreyT said.